# sql task of reporting

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a sql query but I would like to improve them.

```
customer number | amount |  bill |  sum1 | sum2 |  date  | .... (other components)

  1001             -130     F/001     0     -70    2016-01-01

  1001             -80      F/002    -10     0     2016-05-01
```

I would like to have as show below.

the amount in the report is chosen as the most recent of the dates for the account, but with the components sum1 and sum2 in report

```
customer number | amount |   sum1 | sum2 |  date | .... (other components)

  1001             -80        0     -70    2016-05-01

  1001             -80       -10     0     2016-05-01
```

This subquery is owned by the company, I can not show it.

amendment might look just like this

```
 SELECT 
      customer_number, 
      amount,
      sum1,
      sum2,
      date,
      (other components)
 FROM (
      (content of the report)
 ) AS raport 
 WHERE ....
```

I tried with:

```
 SELECT 
      customer_number, 
      amount,
      sum1,
      sum2,
      date, 
      (other components) 
 FROM (
      (content of the report)
 ) AS raport 
QUALIFY ROW NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION customer_number, amount ORDER BY date DESC) = 1
```

but I failed to.

I would ask for some suggestions.

Comment: It seems you want one record returned per customer account in which case the sum1, sum2 or any other field needs to aggregate the values of all rows for the same customer account or not?

Comment: @AnjaniKumarAgrawal - I can see two rows for the same customer in the desired output. How did you conclude that "it seems" otherwise?

Comment: @mathguy - From this line in "the amount in the report is chosen as the most recent of the dates for the account"

Comment: @AnjaniKumarAgrawal - that is only about the value in one column, not all the columns. (However, that part which I missed answers MY question!)

Comment: @mathguy - I agree but if I don't get very well written question I make some assumptions based on the information provided which I verify with questioner...

Comment: I want to have two records, or even more if there are more components.
This column amount of BRM system.
sum1 and sum2 are another source 

amount 
UNION ALL 
sum1 
sum2

Comment: @MartinusP - It looks like you are looking for: 
     order by date desc

Comment: @AnjaniKumarAgrawal yes, but I need only amount order by date desc. the rest remains the same. 
the number of rows must be the same

Comment: What's your Teradata release? TD14.10 supports `FIRST_VALUE`/`LAST_VALUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand your requirement, but perhaps even so this will help. In your original post you flipped the dates, but not the amounts shown in the SUM1 and SUM2 columns. That makes no sense, clearly you made a mistake but I don't know what you wanted there. Anyway, the query below uses the FIRST_VALUE() analytic function, that is probably what you are looking for. If you don't need the ORDER BY clause at the very end, just delete/ignore it.

```
with
     inputs ( customer_number, amount, bill, sum1, sum2, dt ) as (
       select 1001, -130, 'F/001',   0, -70, date '2016-01-01' from dual union all
       select 1001,  -80, 'F/002', -10,   0, date '2016-05-01' from dual
     )
select customer_number, 
       first_value(amount) over (partition by customer_number order by dt desc) as amount,
       bill, sum1, sum2, dt
from   inputs
order by dt desc
;
```

**Output**:

```
CUSTOMER_NUMBER     AMOUNT BILL        SUM1       SUM2 DT
--------------- ---------- ----- ---------- ---------- ----------
           1001        -80 F/002        -10          0 2016-05-01
           1001        -80 F/001          0        -70 2016-01-01
```

Comment: sorry for the translation of the problem, but that's what I meant 
super :)

Answer (score 0):

From the given information I think you are looking for an order by descending clause:

```
 SELECT 
  customer_number, 
  amount,
  sum1,
  sum2,
  date,
  (other components)
FROM (
  (content of the report)
 ) AS raport 
 Order By date desc
```

Comment: I need to value amount order by date desc,
I do not want to sort report data by column